# What is the difference of having to use a ca.crt to verify a signed file vs the .crt used to sign it?

Tags: certificates, hash-signature

This seemed like the most appropriate place to ask this question so here it goes:

I used to run a process that automatically generated a `shim.key` and `shim.crt` along with a `ca.crt` for safe boot signing.  Using the `shim` versions I signd a file like this:

> `sbsign --key path/to/shim.key --cert path/to/shim.crt filetosign`

to verify the file I used the `ca.crt` file like this:

> `sbverify --cert path/to/ca.crt filetosign.signed`

All worked okay.  But trying to verify using `shim.crt`, as shown below, would would *fail*:

> `sbverify --cert path/to/shim.crt filetosign.signed`

The updated process no longer generates the `shim.key`, `shim.crt` or `ca.crt` files automatically, I have to provide it the `shim.crt`.  Looking at the script file I created last year, it appears that I first tried using `efikeygen` but it must not have worked because it's commented out; I don't recall what the problem was and there are no notes in the script. Instead I set it up to create the new `shim.key`  and `shim.crt` file using openssl:

> ```
> openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -x509 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -out shim.crt -keyout shim.key -subj "/CN=Acme UEFI SB 2020/O=Acme Inc/L=New York/ST=New York/C=US" 
> openssl pkcs12 -export -out shim.pfx -inkey shim.key -in shim.crt 
> openssl x509 -outform der -in shim.crt -out shim.cer
> ```

That gave me a `shim.key` and `shim.crt` file, but no `ca.crt` file.

I can *successfully* sign and verify a file as follows:

> ```
> sbsign --key path/to/shim.key --cert path/to/shim.crt filetosign
> sbverify --cert path/to/shim.crt filetosign.signed
> ```

It gets confusing with all the different formats and terms used.

So a couple of questions:

1. Why would the original method, that created a `ca.crt`, not verify using the `shim.crt`, but the new one without the `ca.crt` did?
2. How could I create a `shim.key`, `shim.crt` and `ca.crt` that would work like it originally did?

TIA!!

Comment: `But trying to verify using shim.crt, as shown below, would would fail: sbverify --cert path/to/shim.crt filetosign.signed` - Please let us know what is the error message with which it fails?

Comment: It could be that the certificate is included in the file that you signed, and that you need to provide a CA certificate to verify the chain. These kind of questions are generally better asked on a Q/A site that is more specific to the problem though, because these tools may behave in rather application-specific ways (i.e. the problem isn't so much with the crypto, but the specific way that the program performs the crypto). We'd have to look into the sbsign / sbverify tools to find out...

Comment: Finally got in to system the issue is:  PKCS7 verification failed
140232027154064:error:21075075:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:certificate verify error:pk7_smime.c:328:Verify error:unable to verify the first certificate